# Weird network problems

Tags: nvidia, networking

I'm having some very strange network problems that I have no idea what is causing them. Here are some of the symptoms (across all browsers):

- Random timeouts of webpages.
- Difficulty doing any sort of POST to a webserver. Forum posts, the log in of this forum, etc.
- Some webpages don't load at all: Facebook, Twitter, and others.
- Can't upload any files through any sort of standard HTML post form. At all. It seems to upload a few seconds of the file then just freezes.

It is definitely not the DNS server as I've tried both OpenDNS and the Google DNS servers. I've already tried disabling ipv6 to no avail.

LSPCI doesn't show any information about an ethernet card.

Everything works perfectly fine in Vista though, no problems, so it probably isn't a router/modem issue.

Now, here's where things get weird:
**The exact same symptoms happen on two completely different machines running ubuntu, but neither of them struggle on windows.**

Arguably, if it were my modem/router, things wouldn't work on windows. But, then again, if it were the network drivers Ubuntu uses for my particular card, why is it that I have the same problems on two different machines?

Help is very much appreciated,
Thanks in advance.
- James.

Comment: Give a bit more information about the hardware of the computers (namely network card), that will score you better answers.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)